# Need to remove special characters from strings written in a file in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a text file which contains data. Some special char comes in the file. I need to remove all "special" characters, ie:

```
],à,>,¤,`,ƒ,Š,¥,Œ,^,>¤,Â°,ã,Ãé,â€“Â«Â»°,NÂ,N,º,?¿Ññ,ß,ä,º,ô5,ª,é ,ª,§,Á
```

These need to be replaced with a space chat, not removed.

I have one constraint that I have to store output in a String, because I need to pass that string further in TIBCO. I have written the following code but it is removing everything. As I need to have + and - symbol in file.

```
str = str.replaceAll("[^\\w\\s]*", "");
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: (a) There is no connection between the special characters in the answer and the ones in the code. Please make it clear which characters you want to remove, or which ones you want to keep. (b) What do you mean by "white space, not blank space"?

Comment: blank space?white space?...for others exclude that particular ascii range..or include ascii range of input and then check while input

Comment: it seems that the problem you have is to understand the regex - so I suggest, that you use an online regex tester, like https://regex101.com/

Comment: For white space :`string.replaceAll("\\s+","")`

Comment: @Re Sorry,I had pasted the other code then. Now I have pasted the correct one.

Comment: @RealSkeptic ,I had pasted the other code then. Now I have pasted the correct one. 1) ( ],à,>,¤,`,ƒ,Š,¥,Œ,^,>¤,Â°,ã,Ãé,â€“Â«Â»°,NÂ,N,º,?¿Ññ,ß,ä,º,ô5,ª,é ,ª,§,Á ) these all I want to remove. My files should not remove letters, numbers, +, - (as in 02-03-17 ) , : ,  I  2) By white space I mean after removing special character from ( EF2R¥EW) it should be like (EF2R EW) and not (EF2REW). I hope it is clear

Comment: `sb.toString().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z\\d-+]", " ")` ?

Comment: how come `N` is a special character ?

Comment: I suspect you have an encoding problem (the original string isn't encoded in UTF-8). Solve that first, and only after remove characters you do not want.

Comment: @PavneetSingh Ññ not N

Comment: ],à,>,¤,ƒ,Š,¥,Œ,^,>¤,Â°,ã,Ãé,â€“Â«Â»°,NÂ,`N`,º,?¿Ññ,ß,ä,º,ô5‌​,ª,é ,ª,§,Á

Comment: @PavneetSingh your suggestion is working but it is changing the file content padding and alignment

Comment: add your input and expected output in your post

Comment: @PavneetSingh http://www.filedropper.com/image_4  .I have share my use case.After running your suggestion i am able to remove the undesired character but the text alignment is getting change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if you need to replace with whitespace and not with blank, why are you replacing with blank?

You could just use a white list of all chars you want to *keep* by adding plus and minus signs to the character class:

```
.replaceAll("[^\\w\\s.,+-]", " ")
```

I also added the dot and comma, since you probably want these too.

But it looks like a blanket character would be better, since all chars you don't want are above 127:

```
.replaceAll("[\u0080-\uffff]", " ")
```

You can add other chars you *don't* want to this character class as you need.

**Note:** In both cases, I removed the quantifier `*`, because you want a 1-for-1 replacement. If you use `*` the regex will match between every character, and match a sequence of unwanted chars, which will mess up your file.

Comment: @Bohemain filedropper.com/image_4 .I have share my use case.After running your suggestion i am able to remove the undesired character but the text alignment is getting change.

Comment: @sonu exactly what do you mean by "the alignment is getting changed"? Can you please give an example?

Comment: `+`  will consume one or more matches and all will be replaced with a single space so result in broken alignment

Comment: @Bohemian Please see the use case at http://www.filedropper.com/image_4  . In (afterRunningWithCodeSuggestion.png) You can see that the output text is broken , I want the text file to be like (after.png). After running the code using either of ( replaceAll("[\u0080-\uffff]", " ") ) or ( .replaceAll("[^\\w\\s.,+-]+", " ") ) it is removing the unwanted character but text in o/p file is not in proper format as input text file

Comment: @Bohemian . It is removing all unwanted char except , ( comma ) . Now please suggest how to get rid from comma. I finally used replaceAll("[^\\w\\s.+-:]+", " ")

Comment: @sonuthakur you should remove the "+" after the character class as PavneetSingh suggested

Comment: @Bohemian replaceAll("[^\\w\\s.+-:]", " ") is removing the undesired character. My output text is fine with it .The only issue is it is not replacing ,( comma ) . I want to replace , also . Please help me on this

Comment: @sonu the minus must be last (or first) in the character class, otherwise it's a *range*. Note that your character class includes all the characters between + and : inclusive. If you want to replace commas, try this: `replaceAll("[^\\w\\s.,:+-]", " ")`

Comment: @Bohemian I tried replaceAll("[^\\w\\s.,:+-]", " ") but still it is not removing comma.Any clue ?

Comment: @sonuthakur sorry - I left the comma in. Try this: `replaceAll("[^\\w\\s.:+-]", " ")`

Comment: @Bohemian Thanks a lot

Comment: @PavneetSingh Thanks a lot

Comment: @sonuthakur i am glad that we could help , you should accept this answer , happy coding

Comment: @Bohemian now in my other requirement i have to include " (double quotes) in my output . when i am adding double quote it is giving syntax error.  replaceAll("[^\\w\\s."+-]", " "). any way to include quotes in output and not to filter it. Thanks

Comment: @sonuthakur you need to escape double quotes in Java string literal: add a backslash before the double quote.

Comment: @Bohemian that's great . it is working . Thank you so much

Comment: @Bohemian . In my new requirement I need to have square bracket [ ] in output file . I tried doing it like replaceAll("[^\\w\\s.,\"/'<>_][>%=</?:+-]", ""); but it is not removing any of the special character itself .can you pls guide me as how I can have square bracket in output file. Actually I am doing special char filter for xml file.